# Modify width of all text frames in a document

Tags: adobe-indesign, text, indesign-scripting, book, grep

I have text frames on over 200 pages,
Is possible to select all text frames at once and decrease their width through Text Frame Options or any other method, as the edges of text frames are closely reached to the edge of page, due to misplaning.

Comment: Thank you so much my bro
My problem was solved according to the modification of  Basic Text Frame - Object style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

...I *think* the only thing one could possibly do is alter the "Basic Text Frame" item in the **Object Styles** to add an *interior offset to text frames* with that style applied.

The "Basic Text Frame" style is applied by default to text frames, but that doesn't necessarily mean it hasn't been altered or that there aren't overrides on pages.

Comment: *Size* and *position* can also be set in the object style. Whether or not it works as intended in this case of course depends on how everything is set up.

Comment: @Wolff, that is exactly what I did to solve my problem. Thank U for your comment.